# Closest feature at angle using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, proximity

I have points representing where street light poles meet the ground. I also have the angle which the mast arm is facing. We use this to symbolize the features by showing the mast arm over the appropriate road- sometimes it is not perpendicular to the closest road. I need to associate attributes in the street centerline with the point.

The near tool doesn't do it because you can't specify a specific angle.

Comment: Yes but Generate Near Table can consider all alternatives which can then be reduced by definition/query to just the ones that are within a specific angle. The angle is specific to the source so a join will be needed to correlate the two. Is that what you're after? Do you have any python scripting ability? I think, in the end, when it comes to two choices that seem fairly likely arcpy is going to be needed to find/attribute the closest to the tangent.

Answer (score 1):

I found the [Bearing Distance To Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000ts000000) tool:

> Creates a new feature class containing geodetic line features
>   constructed based on the values in an x-coordinate field, y-coordinate
>   field, bearing field, and distance field of a table.

This worked well.